# How to put a Google Maps with approximate location?

Tags: android, maps

In facebook marketplace they put a map, then encircled the approximate location of the seller's address. How am I going to implement it in android studio? here's a screenshot from facebook marketplace. [Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4GF5.png)

Comment: What have you done up until now?

Comment: integrate google map, get users current location using fused location provider client, once you get user location , draw circle around it using CircleOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after integrating google map you can use following code

```
GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 // Add a circle in Sydney
 Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689))
     .radius(10000)
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```